# Slideshow revolution automatically display slide on specific day's of the week

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, joomla3.0

I'm using Joomla slideshow revolution and I was wondering how can I created an automated script that will check the day to change the value from unpublished to published on my database table according to the day on the label on checkbox?.[image]

This is just an idea

```
if(date('D', $timestamp) === 'Mon') 
check if slide_id status == unpublised 
then change status to publish
```

Comment: What is your concrete question here? And better use `N` (numeric representation of the day of the week ) instead of `D`.

Comment: How can I created an automated script that will check the day to change the value from unpublished to published on my database table according to the day on the label on checkbox?

Comment: Tips: set up a cronjop in crontab (on linux), write a script that does check the day and update the database. If you can not do a cronjob, include the script elsewhere and run it once a day. If you want to do this in a Joomla Component/Plugin, read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I refuse to use crontab to accomplished this task I know there is way to accomplished this implementing Jquery and php I'll just have to figure it out. basically i can use Jquery auto-refresh script to constantly check for what day is but I still missing the rest.